# How do I log out of qtile?

Tags: login, mate

I installed and launched qtile in ubuntu(mate) but as I do not know how to use it yet, I want to log out. Unfortunately, my computer is set to log in automatically on startup so I am not given the choice after restart. I just need a simple way to log out of the Qtile window manager which I have installed on an Ubuntu Mate machine. I do not even know how to launch terminal in here: ctrl-alt-t doesn't work, super-r will launch my browser but wont launch anything else(including terminal). 
I went to some tty or something but then I realized I had forgotten my username so I can't login with just my password.. It is due to having reinstalled the system a million times over a short period of time, creating a different user every time.

Is there any way to log out of Qtile?

Answer (score -1):

To logout: `super + control + q`

see

https://github.com/qtile/qtile/blob/v0.14.2/libqtile/resources/default_config.py#L62

To launch a terminal use `super+r` then type `gnome-terminal` then hit 'Enter' key. Alternatively install xterm `sudo apt install xterm`, then use the keyboard shortcut `super+enter` to launch it. See https://github.com/qtile/qtile/blob/v0.14.2/libqtile/resources/default_config.py#L55

You can also configure `super+enter` to launch gnome-terminal instead of xterm:

```sh
# create a config file if you don't have one
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qtile/qtile/v0.14.2/libqtile/resources/default_config.py --output ~/.config/qtile/config.py --create-dirs
```

edit `~/.config/qtile/config.py` and change `xterm` to `gnome-terminal` or your preferred terminal, then restart qtile with `super+control+r`